# UISwipeGestureRecognizer without touch down

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

How do I recognise a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` with `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp` and then directly after that, WITHOUT lifting my finger, recognise a `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown` recogniser?

Basically I want multiple `UISwipeGestureRecognizers` being recognised without lifting my finger when I change direction.

**My code so far...**

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {        
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(screenSwipedUp)];
        swipeUp.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
        swipeUp.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(screenSwipedDown)];
        swipeDown.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
        swipeDown.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];

    }

    - (void)screenSwipedUp {
        NSLog(@"SW-Up");
    }

    - (void)screenSwipedDown {
        NSLog(@"SW-Down");
    }
```

Comment: I think you trying to implement `Drag` rather than `Swipe` ?

Comment: `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is the right tool. There are also some libraries out there that provide recognition of complex gestures (google "iOS gesture recognizer shape" or "iOS gesture recognizer complex"), but this is simple enough that I'd be inclined to just detect it myself in my own pan gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it with [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can instead use [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and implement the action OR create a subclass of [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer) and [Override the methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer) to recognize your special gesture.